# argo-events EventSource not detecting any update when using k8s object deployments

Tags: kubernetes, argoproj, argo-events

Event source logs show no error when deployed, but when we make changes on the k8s object deployments. There is nothing that happened in the logs, and the Sensor didn't get triggered.
But when i use Webhook as the EventSource everything works fine.

EventSource logs doesn't show new logs after I makes the changes on the Deployments which mean that the EventSource not detecting anything

Logs

```
{"level":"info","ts":1686886342.173714,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"cmd/start.go:63","msg":"starting eventsource server","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","version":"v1.8.0"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886342.1739395,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"metrics/metrics.go:175","msg":"starting metrics server","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886342.176743,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"leaderelection/leaderelection.go:153","msg":"Not the LEADER, stand by ...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1804671,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"leaderelection/leaderelection.go:162","msg":"Becoming a Candidate, stand by ...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.181508,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"leaderelection/leaderelection.go:159","msg":"I'm the LEADER, starting ...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1815512,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"eventsources/eventing.go:432","msg":"Starting event source server...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1827407,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"eventbus/driver.go:36","msg":"eventBusConfig: {NATS:&NATSConfig{URL:nats://eventbus-default-stan-svc:4222,ClusterID:*eventbus-default,Auth:*token,AccessSecret:&v1.SecretKeySelector{LocalObjectReference:LocalObjectReference{Name:eventbus-default-client,},Key:client-auth,Optional:nil,},} JetStream:nil Kafka:nil}","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.183087,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"base/stan.go:48","msg":"NATS auth strategy: Token","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","clientID":"client-resource-eventssource-eventsource-42kv4-7c5c79f6b7-s78qn-613"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.184984,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"base/stan.go:60","msg":"Connected to NATS server.","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","clientID":"client-resource-eventssource-eventsource-42kv4-7c5c79f6b7-s78qn-613"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1882076,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"base/stan.go:73","msg":"Connected to NATS streaming server.","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","clientID":"client-resource-eventssource-eventsource-42kv4-7c5c79f6b7-s78qn-613"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1884556,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"eventsources/eventing.go:581","msg":"Eventing server started.","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1885884,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"eventsources/eventing.go:459","msg":"starting eventbus connection daemon...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1887667,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"resource/start.go:85","msg":"setting up a K8s client","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","eventSourceType":"resource","eventName":"example"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1890445,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"resource/start.go:108","msg":"configuring label selectors if filters are selected...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","eventSourceType":"resource","eventName":"example"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1890962,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"resource/start.go:121","msg":"setting up informer factory...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","eventSourceType":"resource","eventName":"example"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1891494,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"resource/start.go:234","msg":"running informer...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","eventSourceType":"resource","eventName":"example"}
{"level":"info","ts":1686886343.1895285,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource","caller":"resource/start.go:174","msg":"listening to resource events...","eventSourceName":"resource-eventssource","eventSourceType":"resource","eventName":"example"}
Stream closed EOF for argo-events/resource-eventssource-eventsource-42kv4-7c5c79f6b7-s78qn (main)
```

i'm using argo-events v1.8.0

sample EventSource

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: EventSource
metadata:
  name: resource-eventssource
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: serviceAccount
  resource:
    example:
      namespace: argo-events
      group: apps
      version: v1
      resource: deployments
      eventTypes:
        - UPDATE
      filter:
        afterStart: false
        labels:
          - key: app
            operation: "=="
            value: webserver
```